# ¿Cómo agregar números decimales en la exportación de un archivo .csv?

Tags: angular, csv, angular-material

me acabo de percatar que tengo un problema y no sé como solucionarlo, tengo un `multi select` que lista áreas, y a su vez estas tienen su id y densidad que cómo veŕan están en número decimal:

```
 this.areas = [
      {id: 1, name: "AREA 1", densidad: "12,3"},
      {id: 2, name: "AREA 2", densidad: "11,3"},
      {id: 3, name: "AREA 3", densidad: "15,09"},
      {id: 4, name: "AREA 4", densidad: "11,4"},
      {id: 5, name: "AREA 5", densidad: "13,8"}
    ]
```

Se pueden seleccionar todas o algunas para después exportarlo, pero me los muestra así de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé como hacer que la función de `ConvertToCSV` no me deje todos los números después de la coma en la siguiente fila. Aquí les dejo la [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-select-report?embed=1&file=src/app/services/report.service.ts) para que me puedan orientar un poco. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución sería devolver entre comillas los datos del csv:

```
ConvertToCSV(objArray, headerList) {
  let array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
  let str = '';
  let row = '';

  for (let index in headerList) {
      row += headerList[index] + ',';
  }
  row = row.slice(0, -1);
  str += row + '\r\n';
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      let line = '';
      for (let index in headerList) {
         let head = headerList[index];
          // esta es la modificación
          line += `"${array[i][head]}"` + ',';
      }
      str += line + '\r\n';
  }
  return str;
}
```

O si solo quieres la columna densidad entre comillas puedes agregar una condición:

```
for (let index in headerList) {
         let head = headerList[index];
          if(head === "densidad")
            line += `"${array[i][head]}"` + ',';
          else
          line += array[i][head] + ',';
      }
```

Comment: O eso era lo que necesitaba, era algo tan  pequeño por modificar.